# Master page with more then 1 form?

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, master-pages

So, I know you can only have 1 `runat="server"` and `<form>` per master page.  My question is, how do I put my login FORM on my website? Do I put it all on the master page? Or some on the page and some on the .aspx form? Right now I have it mostly on Master, and the `onClick()` event on the .aspx page. I'll postcode at the below.

My Login.ASPX page.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">


</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="#login" type="submit" onclick="openForm()">Login</a>
    </div>

    <p style="text-align: center">WELCOME HOME</p>

</asp:Content>
```

Here is my Master page code

```
<head runat="server">
    <link href="CSS/StyleCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>11</title>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1> 11MO</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="PopupPosition">
        <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
            <form class="form-container" id="form1" runat="server">
                <h1>Login Form</h1>
                <p style="text-align: center">Please login using your <strong><em>User ID and Password</em></strong></p>


                <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="User Name:"> </asp:Label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>

                <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password:"> </asp:Label>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"> </asp:TextBox>

                <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Width="315px" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" Text="Login"></asp:Button>

                <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <footer class="Footer">
        <p>&copy; 2020 - Application Homepage</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function openForm() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeForm() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

**RESULT** I would like to get the code all on 1 page, be it master or login. I've tried putting it all in the `ContentPlaceHolder1` area and it doesn't work. I think it's because I have 2 server run operations when I do that. So, how do I get it all on 1 page, but still keep the format for my other pages available. I also have Tiles that I want to be transferred so I'll haft to keep that on the master. Will I haft to add a sub Master page?

Comment: You can have as many runat="server" attributes as you want. What does " it doesn't work" mean? What error are you getting?

Comment: @IrishChieftain It doesn't load. It gets a 2 forms error.

Comment: We need more details - can you post the exact error you're getting? I only see one form tag, in your master page. Have you identified where the other form tag is located?

Comment: @IrishChieftain I edited it many times to show the different types of code I used. I actually fixed it by realizing what ContentPlaceHolder did and utilizing that.

Comment: Then post this as an answer and mark it correct when able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the article to create login form using master pages 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/simple-login-form-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: This article demonstrates how to make a login form using ASPX page. Not master pages.

Comment: did you try to use the project template for the ASP.net webform? they have login form inside master pages

Comment: I did, and it still gave a error, I fixed it by finding out what ContentPlaceHolder was used for and did. Now I'm good. Thank you.